# What is the difference between Window Presentation Foundation and WCF? Which is newer?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wcf

So which one is the newer one, and why would I use one over the other. Or more importantly, over Windows Forms?

Comment: WPF and WCF are entirely different. 
WPF is for rich GUI application. WCF is for service oriented applications. WCF unifies Webserives+ remoting+ message queues+ into a single API. WPF is better choice over Windows forms, though you would have to invest time and efforts into it. WPF and WCF would solve different business problems.

Comment: Which is newer: rocket ships or vanilla beans?  Why should I use one or the other?

Comment: vanilla beans are newer Mike, everyone knows that! *DOH*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither is newer than the other, they have both been cooking for roughly the same period of time.

HOWEVER they are totally different things :

WPF == Windows Presentation Foundation
WCF == Windows Communication Foundation

WPF is the direct replacement for WinForms. WCF is a framework for talking to webservices, it replaces Remoting. I could waffle for hours on this, but that is a short answer for you :)

Comment: WPF is much, much more powerful than WinForms, and more efficient to work with too.  Compare WinForms with raw GDI calls and WndProcs, and you will have some idea of the difference.  Many things that are easy to do in WinForms are even easier in WPF, and many things that are nearly impossible in WinForms are easy in WPF.  If you have a choice, WPF is almost always better than WinForms.  The only exceptions are if you are running on embedded hardware with very limited performance, hardware over 10-12 years old, or must support Windows 2000 or Windows 9x.

Comment: @slugster You cannot say **it replaces Remoting**. Remoting is still used for [App domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain) communication.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft websites:

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) is...

a part of the .NET Framework that provides a unified programming model for rapidly building service-oriented applications that communicate across the web and the enterprise..

---

[Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)

Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) provides developers with a unified programming model for building rich Windows smart client user experiences that incorporate UI, media, and documents.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is NOT a replacement for WinForms.  Consider LOB applications, running on bulk enterprise hardware.  The overhead of WPF is ridiculous.

Consider the following  On my machine I have VS2008 and VS2010 installed.

Visual Studio 2008 (WinForms I believe) is only ~100mb of memory.

Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 (WPF) is ~300mb.

That's just stupid.  There's no reason for VS to be using WPF.  It doesn't need flashy graphics or anything special that WPF offers.  I'm for one sticking to VS2008.  There's a time and a place when WPF is great to use, but Visual Studio and as I said LOB applications are not the time or place, it's just adding ridiculous overhead for pointless reasons.

However, WPF is a lot easier to work with than WinForms (once you UNDERSTAND it, the learning curve is also a lot larger)

Comment: Uh, you didn't think that through, yeah? WPF is the next generation on from WinForms, hence my comment about "replacement".

As for why VS2010 is done in WPF.... i imagine it must be a whole bunch easier to do WPF rendering/layout etc when your IDE is written in WPF than it would be when the IDE is still predominantly C++ and COM based like VS2008.

Comment: ITS NOT A REPLACEMENT.  Microsoft has no intentions of discontinuing WinForms

Comment: Duh, nobody ever said WinForms was going to be replaced, i don't know how you managed to read that into what i said. It most certainly is a replacement, in the same way that WinForms & .Net is a replacement for VB/MFC etc, you can still code in those older technologies if you wish, but fewer and fewer people are doing so. If you don't like the word "replacement" then think "next generation".