# WindowsPresentationFoundation Vs Windows Communication Foundation

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Can anyone tell me the difference b/W WPF and WCF?Does WCF uses only IIS?

Comment: Actually you are asking about two different technology and used for two entirely different purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Window Presentation Foundation and WCF? Which is newer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712670/what-is-the-difference-between-window-presentation-foundation-and-wcf-which-is-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is a presentation technology while WCF is a communication technology.

No , WCF can be hosted in a Console/Windows Service also

Answer (score 0):

WCF - is some what in line with your web services, Named pipes etc. Basically it used to provide service through web, tcp , pipes etc ... The advantage of wcf over others is the implementation of the logic can be done once and the mode of communication like HTTP or TCP are just configurable through end points

WPF - Is purely a presentation framework. This mainly deals with XAML. What this tries to achieve is to separate the presentation & the business logic.

Not very familiar with WPF but this is the basic difference

Answer (score 0):

wpf it's like windows forms :) WPF based on XAML (special format of xml, which describe your controls).
wcf - it's web service.

wpf and wcf are absolutely difference :)

Answer (score 0):

you will get better idea from this

[What is the difference between Window Presentation Foundation and WCF? Which is newer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712670/what-is-the-difference-between-window-presentation-foundation-and-wcf-which-is-n)